# Is there a way to change the action performed by the PrtScr key?

Tags: windows, keyboard

I have a question regarding the PrtScr key.
By toggling a setting in Windows 10, you can set the PrtScr key to launch the command `ms-screenclip:` which launches the new snipping tool built-in in Windows. Is there a way to change the action this key performs on keypress, preferably without using 3rd parts software?

Answer (score 2):

There is actually not something for this task built in to windows but their is a app provided by microsoft itself (Not third party as you said) the app name is **Microsoft mouse and keyboard center** here is the [Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/mouse-and-keyboard-center-download-f5b10905-7887-eedb-2f1c-d0737a36a3b2)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/mouse-and-keyboard-center-download-f5b10905-7887-eedb-2f1c-d0737a36a3b2 - unformatted too

Comment: It looks like it only supports Microsoft devices thus not detecting my Asus keyboard :// Thanks for your answer anyway

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't noticed, it worked with me so I recommended it